# Cannot Create Code Signing Identity

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

My team is transferring the app we are developing from one mac to another and are running into issues code signing.

We exported the certificate from the old computer as a .p12 file and installed it on the **login** keychain of the new computer.  We also went to **Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Gear Icon > Export Developer Accounts** on the old computer, then imported the Developer Account on the new computer.

When we try to run the app on an iPhone, however, we get this error, even though (as far as we know), we imported the correct certificate and private key:

> "No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier "com.our.bundle.identifier" were found.

Following the directions we found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html), we figured we had to create an iOS Development code signing identity.  The screen where we tried to do this looks like this:

[image]

However, when we click "Create" the create button simply goes gray, never seeming to create an iOS Development signing identity.  The screen looks like this:

[image]

How can we create a signing identity and use it to develop on another mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this error multiple times and what solves it for me is the following:

1. In the list with the view that you have attached, right click on each row and move each certificate to trash
2. Go to member center download the right certificates again and click on them so
3. **Restart Xcode**
4. Go to build settings and set the right Code signing for release - you should be able to see an option on the row that says "Identities from profile..."

If this doesn't work then you should consider revoking your certificate and then create a new one and the do the steps above again.

Comment: What fixed it for us was getting rid of our old certificates & provisioning profiles.  We had to delete the ones we weren't using any more.